# Behaviour of function SDL_FreeSurface: why it crashes in this context?

Tags: c++, c, sdl

I am learning SDL with an online tutorial and found a problem I do not understand.
Accordingly to the tutorial, it is good practice to always correctly free the resources used by your application. In my case, I want to free the memory used by the SDL surfaces.

However, one `SDL_FreeSurface` crashes my program in the exit if I do not set the pointer it is going to free to `nullptr` BEFORE calling the function.

This does not occur with any other surfaces. Even solving the problem by changing order of statements, I dislike ''cargo cult''. I want to understand **WHY** in this specific case I need to make the pointer nullptr **BEFORE** freeing the memory.

This is the code:

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>

int main (void) {SDL_SetMainReady();

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    enum image_list{ /* set enum */ };

    SDL_Window  * ptr_Window = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface * ptr_Canvas = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface * ptr_Mask   = nullptr;     // this is the pointer with problem
    SDL_Surface * array_list_of_images[enum_Total]; /* each array initialized correctly */

    ptr_Mask = array_list_of_images[enum_Image_Default]; // here the problematic pointer is set to array[0]

    /* code */

    // Here is where the pointer is used:
    switch (union_events_holder.key.keysym.sym){
        case SDLK_UP    : ptr_Mask = array_list_of_images[enum_Image_Up]; break;
        case SDLK_DOWN  : ptr_Mask = array_list_of_images[enum_Image_Down]; break;
        case SDLK_LEFT  : ptr_Mask = array_list_of_images[enum_Image_Left]; break;
        case SDLK_RIGHT : ptr_Mask = array_list_of_images[enum_Image_Right]; break;
        default         : ptr_Mask = array_list_of_images[enum_Image_Default]; break;

    /* more code */

    SDL_BlitSurface(ptr_Mask , NULL , ptr_Canvas , NULL );
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(ptr_Window);

    /* more code */

    // HERE OCCURS THE PROBLEM.
    // WITHOUT POINTING ptr_Mask TO NULL BEFORE CALLING SDL_FreeSurface,
    // THE APP CRASHES.

    ptr_Mask    = nullptr;
    SDL_FreeSurface(ptr_Mask); // This cannot be called before previous statement. Why?

    for ( int ctd = 0 ; ctd < enum_Total ; ++ctd){
        SDL_FreeSurface(array_list_of_images[ctd]);
        array_list_of_images[ctd] = nullptr; // Here it is safe to set pointer to nullptr AFTER freeing memory.
    }   

    SDL_FreeSurface(ptr_Canvas);   
    SDL_DestroyWindow(ptr_Window);

    ptr_Canvas       = nullptr; // Here also it is safe to set pointer to nullptr AFTER freeing memory.
    ptr_Window       = nullptr;

    SDL_Quit();

return (0);}
```

Notes:

- Tagged as C because SDL. I am coding with C++.
- Found the bug proceeding manual step-by-step with `std::cerr` + `std::cin.get()`
- `SDL_GetError()` cannot output info because both Window and console crash when the function is called.
- I suspected of undefined behaviour of dereferencing `nullptr`, but it makes no sense, once the function only works exactly when I set to `nullptr`.

**EDIT - This is the full code (variables in Brazilian portuguese)**

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>

int main (void) {SDL_SetMainReady();

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window  * ptr_Janela = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface * ptr_Tela   = nullptr;

    enum lista_de_imagens{
        LIMG_Imagem_Default, 
        LIMG_Imagem_Cima,
        LIMG_Imagem_Baixo,
        LIMG_Imagem_Esquerda,
        LIMG_Imagem_Direita,
        LIMG_Total_de_imagens
    };

    SDL_Surface * l_lista_de_imagens[LIMG_Total_de_imagens]; 

        l_lista_de_imagens[LIMG_Imagem_Default]   = SDL_LoadBMP("Lesson4/Default.bmp" );
        l_lista_de_imagens[LIMG_Imagem_Cima]      = SDL_LoadBMP("Lesson4/Cima.bmp"    );
        l_lista_de_imagens[LIMG_Imagem_Baixo]     = SDL_LoadBMP("Lesson4/Baixo.bmp"   );
        l_lista_de_imagens[LIMG_Imagem_Esquerda]  = SDL_LoadBMP("Lesson4/Esquerda.bmp");
        l_lista_de_imagens[LIMG_Imagem_Direita]   = SDL_LoadBMP("Lesson4/Direita.bmp" );
        l_lista_de_imagens[LIMG_Total_de_imagens ]= nullptr;

    SDL_Surface * ptr_mascara = nullptr;

    ptr_Janela = SDL_CreateWindow("Lesson 4 - Show image as keyboard inputs",
                                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                640, //SCREEN_WIDTH,
                                480, //SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                                SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    ptr_Tela = SDL_GetWindowSurface(ptr_Janela);

    SDL_BlitSurface(l_lista_de_imagens[LIMG_Imagem_Default] , NULL , ptr_Tela , NULL );
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(ptr_Janela);

    SDL_Event u_Gerenciador_de_eventos;
    bool sair = false;

    ptr_mascara = l_lista_de_imagens[LIMG_Imagem_Default];

    while(!sair){

            while(SDL_PollEvent(&u_Gerenciador_de_eventos) !=0){

                if(u_Gerenciador_de_eventos.type == SDL_QUIT){sair = true;}
                if( u_Gerenciador_de_eventos.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){

                    switch (u_Gerenciador_de_eventos.key.keysym.sym){

                        case SDLK_UP    : ptr_mascara = l_lista_de_imagens[LIMG_Imagem_Cima]; break;

                        case SDLK_DOWN  : ptr_mascara = l_lista_de_imagens[LIMG_Imagem_Baixo]; break;

                        case SDLK_LEFT  : ptr_mascara = l_lista_de_imagens[LIMG_Imagem_Esquerda]; break;

                        case SDLK_RIGHT : ptr_mascara = l_lista_de_imagens[LIMG_Imagem_Direita]; break;

                        default         : ptr_mascara = l_lista_de_imagens[LIMG_Imagem_Default]; break;

                    /*end switch*/}

                /*end if*/}

        /*end laço de eventos*/}

    SDL_BlitSurface(ptr_mascara , NULL , ptr_Tela , NULL );
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(ptr_Janela);

    /*end laço principal*/}

    ptr_mascara    = nullptr;
    SDL_FreeSurface(ptr_mascara); 

    for ( int ctd = 0 ; ctd < LIMG_Total_de_imagens ; ++ctd){
        SDL_FreeSurface(l_lista_de_imagens[ctd]);
        l_lista_de_imagens[ctd] = nullptr;
    /*end for*/}    

    SDL_FreeSurface(ptr_Tela);   
    SDL_DestroyWindow(ptr_Janela);

    ptr_Tela       = nullptr;
    ptr_Janela     = nullptr;

    SDL_Quit();

return (0);
/*end main*/}
```

Comment: `SDL_FreeSurface` does nothing if you give it a null pointer (the documentation explicitly states "It is safe to pass NULL to this function") , but you will get undefined behavior if you give it an invalid pointer. That being said, you don't seem to assign anything of value to `ptr_Canvas`? Is it your intention?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel This is what I am trying to understand: why is this pointer invalid to be used with SDL_FreeSurface?

Comment: If never assign anything to `ptr_Canvas`, how is it supposed to point to something valid?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel That is not the full code. I only selected the parts where the pointer is used.

Comment: Then your issue is in the code you didn't show.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I will upload it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected surface gets freed twice.

You have two pointers to the same image. The first one is in `l_lista_de_imagens[LIMG_Imagem_Default]` and the second one is in `ptr_mascara`.

When you do `SDL_FreeSurface(ptr_mascara)` and then `SDL_FreeSurface(l_lista_de_imagens[ctd]);` you are freeing the same surface twice.

`SDL_FreeSurface(nullptr)` doesn't do anything, so when you add `ptr_mascara = nullptr;` before `SDL_FreeSurface(ptr_mascara)`, you are only freeing the surface once.

Comment: But when I free inside the for loop (the array), there is no crash. The crash only occurs with ptr_mascara, not otherwise. It can be done before or after the for loop and the results are the same: only when called to free ptr_mascara the app crashes.

Comment: My bad. I remenber now it also crashed in such circunstances.